# What image gallery? [iPhone]

Tags: iphone, scrollview

[image]

Hey guys,
checkout this. How can I do something similar? I mean a scrollview with 9x9 images.
Also, how can I put a custom loading image??

Ty.

Answer (score 1):

Allocate and init a UIScrollView, add it to the viewcontroller's view, and then create UIImageViews, set their respective images, and add the image views to the scroll view.

Specifying launch images - get a pic, rename it to Default.png (also might want to get a 2x sized one - call it Default@2x.png) and copy it to the resources folder.

Comment: Sorry man, I mean the loading image in this screen. Look the grey hearts. Those are the placeholder images while the real images loading.

Comment: Ok then whenever you are creating that view put placeholder images in. Whenever your real image loading code takes place, as soon as it the image is ready issue a notification, i.e. "PictureReady". In that view that is shown in the picture listen to these notifications, and when you get one - load the actual image. Can add a nice animation with fading and stuff too...

Answer (score 1):

Use some pre-existing code. AQGridView is a solid piece of grid code.